# how to get 1-100 using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get something like:

```
    Hello, 0 ( dont get )
    Hello2, 100 ( get )
    hello3, 82 ( get )
    hello< 132 ( dont get )
```

I've made something like this so far:

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,255},([0-9]{1,3})(?<![0])
```

But it can't get `132` and `100`. How can I fix this?

Comment: the answer apart, when you ask a question about a regex, you **should** specify what kind of regex you are talking about. Here I assumed it is Perl-like or ECMAScript-like.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this regex which matches a number of 1 or 2 digits, or 100:

```
\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100
```

Comment: how does that work? i can read a little, but the ?!\d ? what the hell is that? `[a-zA-Z]{1,255},([1-9]{1,3}(?!\d)|100)` work great for me but still get 132 etc.

Comment: `(?! ... )`  is a negative lookahead assertion, as `(?<! ... )` is a negative lookbehind assertion, `(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind assertion and `(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead assertion. So this ensures that all digits have been consumed because I explicitly ask that the following character is not a digit.

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: If you get numbers more than 100 it is because you didn't integrate it into your own regexp, and it can also match in the middle of a number.

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: Do not use `[1-9]` but `\d` if you want to be able to match 80, 40, 10, etc. If you want to be sure there is no leading 0, use `([1-9]\d{0,1}(?!\d)|100)`

Answer (score 4):

Why not keeping it simple?

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,255}, (100|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])$
```

or better yet

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,255}, (100|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

note: this won't match prepended zeros e.g. "Hello, 00001". It can be easily extended, though:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,255}, 0*(100|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. It will match 1 to 99  or 100. Number greater than 100 will be invalid.

```
(?:\b|-)([0-9]{1,2}|100)\b
```

Fiddle Link..
https://regex101.com/r/mN1iT5/462

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it by combining regex and arithmetical condition:

1) String is a number: regex match [0-9]+

AND

2) The number is between 1..100.

For example, in bash:

```
N=100

[[ "$N" =~ ^([0-9]+)$ ]] && (( $N>0 && $N<=100 )) && echo YES || echo NO
# YES

[[ "$N" =~ ^([0-9]+)$ && "$N" -le "100" && "$N" -gt "0" ]] && echo YES || echo NO
# YES


N=0

[[ "$N" =~ ^([0-9]+)$ ]] && (( $N>0 && $N<=100 )) && echo YES || echo NO 
# NO

[[ "$N" =~ ^([0-9]+)$ && "$N" -le "100" && "$N" -gt "0" ]] && echo YES || echo NO
# NO
```